# PySpark: map/filter versus list comprehension

Tags: python, pyspark, list-comprehension, udf

Is there any advantages or drawbacks of using Python functions `map` and `filter` versus list comprehensions in a Spark udf from performance, stability or other perepective? I have background in Python and just started to use PySpark. I have came across some examples using `map` and `filter` to manipulate lists inside a Spark udf (`pyspark.sql.functions.udf`) and I wondered if it is just matter of choice (more Hadoop-like style) or more efficient to use than list comprehensions. I use Spark 1.6 if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: Python list comprehensions only operate on local data, whereas (presumably) the PySpark map/filter functions can be farmed out to multiple processes or virtual machines.

Comment: @BenHoyt:  I do not mean the Spark `map` and `filter` of `pyspark.RDD` but using the Python `map` and `filter` commands to manipulate lists inside a Spark udf (`pyspark.sql.functions.udf`).